# Arcgis with JavaScript - Graphics Layer not showing

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I have added graphics layer to my map but it’s not showing up. Under the layer list widget it’s forever loading. However if graphics are added to the feature layer, it will be shown. Any idea why?

Any help will be appreciated been stuck at this like forever!

Tried adding graphics layer inside and outside of useEffect, not working. Tried adding graphics layer to dependency array not working either.

Comment: Hey can you share some code to make this easier to answer?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.